# Cannot assign array value in ngAfterViewInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have an input field. Which will populate a list when I enter something in it. The problem I'm having is that I cannot empty an array value inside ngAfterViewInit()

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {

      // remove suggestion field when goes out of focus()
        if (!$('.suggestionInput').is(':focus')) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.exmapleArray = [];
              }, 50)
            }
        });
    }
```

**exampleArray** not updating to empty array though after debugging found out **if (!$('.suggestionInput').is(':focus'))** is working. But still array value isn't updating. I don't found any reason to support the cause.

I have tried using angular **blur()** inside input but it doesn't server my purpose and other solution regarding ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: Are you using jQuery with Angular?

Comment: maybe just typo? "exmapleArray" in code and "exampleArray" in question

Comment: @HarunYilmaz yes there is jquery

Comment: @Nikolay I have reconfirmed for typos but its same

Comment: Then there are a few things that are not right. First, it's not a good practice to have both Angular and jQuery in the same place. Second, the`.is()` function runs only once as well as the `ngAfterViewInit()`. Therefore, you cannot have a reactive solution like this. I'd suggest you use event handlers provided by Angular like `(blur)="doSomething()"`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I tried **(blur)** approach but it doesn't serve the purpose. And I checked `.is()` working everytime

Comment: Then I suppose I misunderstood your purpose. Can you please clarify further your problem by including the template part and explaining the workflow?